# Find value and return row in excel spreadsheet with over 1 mil rows

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that has over 1 million rows and about 120 columns. I frequently need to find a value or a part of a value (value is name or number) and return the row where the value is found. I only need values from about 20 columns so I could drop out the extra columns but that does not solve the problem of excel being very slow in finding the value and it is very difficult to read information in the row.

What would you recommend to use for this task? Ideally I would like to enter the value and get the row in some sort of a report but not necessary as long as it is well readable.

I was thinking of using Power BI but got kind of stuck and in the end felt that it wasn't the right tool for the task.

I am open for all suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

> the problem of excel being very slow in finding the value and it is
>   very difficult to read information in the row

What is "slow" for you (in seconds) and how fast would you like the search to be?

In a lot of cases, the performance can be considerably improved by [using `INDEX` and `MATCH`](https://www.google.com/search?q=INDEX%20and%20MATCH%20Excel&oq=INDEX%20and%20MATCH%20Excel&aqs=chrome..69i57.7520j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to search for values in Excel, instead of using `VLOOKUP` (which is known to be much slower in comparison).

Alternatively, you could [install SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) on your machine, import the Excel file into a table, and use some SQL statements to find the values you want.

Power BI is a visualization tool, and doesn't seem appropriate for what you're describing which is *preparing the data*. You could use Power BI after, of course, to plot the final results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a pandas Dataframe in python (it has excel read in capability).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(excel_name)
df = df[ df.column_name_you_search_in.str.contains(pattern)]
# print the output
print(df)
# save the output as csv
df.to_csv("temp_file.csv")
```

As a more general comment I think the excel file is not sustainable as you are already almost at its maximum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65536_(number))

Comment: I am used to use Pandas myself but in this case I have to have this search accessible for a few team members. What would be the best way for me to have it accessible for them?

Comment: Can they run a python console? Do they have python on their device?

Comment: No they do not, but I could set it up. I will however have to have it as user friendly as possible. Perhaps use Jupiter Notebook?

Comment: Yes, or you could make it in an executable that takes (console) input and delivers an output csv file.  This way they do not even have to know python.